Microsoft EntraAD- Removed tenant
I need help restoring a tenant that was deleted, unfortunately I don't have access to the account in the organization. What should I do? How can I contact support?
Currently, my account has also been deleted.
I called support Microsoft and Azure, but they only work from 9 a.m. to 5 p.m., Monday to Friday.

Are you sure you didn't just delete your own account? It's pretty hard to delete a tenant. I posted an answer in any case.

Usually, you'd need a premier support plan to get 24/7 support. However, you may be able to get some success with one of the following:

Contact Microsoft Support Outside Business Hours:

Microsoft Global Customer Service Phone Numbers: Check if there is an emergency support number or a different contact number that handles urgent issues outside regular business hours. You can find a list of global customer service phone numbers on the Microsoft support page.
Microsoft Azure Support Plans: If your organization has a support plan that includes 24/7 support, use the contact methods provided with that plan. The support plan details can be accessed by someone in your organization who still has access.


Reach Out to Microsoft Support via Online Channels:

Azure Portal: If anyone in your organization still has access to the Azure portal, they can open a support request directly from there.
Microsoft Support Website: Go to the Microsoft Support website and look for chat or email support options that might be available outside of regular hours.
Microsoft Tech Community: Post your issue on the Microsoft Tech Community forums. Sometimes Microsoft employees or knowledgeable community members can provide guidance on urgent issues.


Escalate the Issue:

If you have already contacted support but need to escalate the issue, ask for a supervisor or higher-level support. Explain the urgency and potential business impact of the issue.


Microsoft Partner or Reseller:

If your organization is working with a Microsoft Partner or reseller, they might have additional support resources or direct contacts within Microsoft that can expedite the resolution.


Alternative Contacts:

Microsoft Premier Support: If your organization has a Premier Support contract, there should be dedicated contacts available. Look for any documentation or emails related to the support contract for emergency contact details.


Document Everything:

Keep detailed records of all your communications with Microsoft support. Note down case numbers, names of support representatives, and summaries of each interaction. This can help in escalating the issue if needed.


Prepare Information:

When you contact support, be ready to provide as much information as possible, including:

Tenant ID (if known)
Subscription ID
Details of the deleted tenant and account
The exact time and date of deletion
Any other relevant details





While these steps might not guarantee immediate resolution, they can help you navigate through the support process more effectively. Restoring a deleted tenant is a critical task, and persistence is key in ensuring your issue gets the necessary attention.
